# Different first row for a UITableView

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, uiimage

I need a `UITableView` whose first row should show a logo, while other rows should show the other table datas.
I tried the following code:

```
if(indexPath.row == 0) {
    //Code for imageview
} else {
    //Code to display array content
}
```

My problem is that I don't get the first array item in the table view.

Edited::

```
if (indexPath.row == 0) {

        CGRect myImageRect = CGRectMake(120.0f, 5.0f, 70.0f, 55.0f);
        UIImageView *myImage = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:myImageRect];
        [myImage setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo.png"]];
        [cell.contentView addSubview:myImage];
    }
    else  {

       NSDictionary *dict = [menuitems objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

        cell.textLabel.text =[dict objectForKey:@"category"]; 
       }
```

Comment: if(indexPath.row == 0) is correct, can you post the -----Code for imageview----?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try to use an headerview. Use the following code to place logo at the top of row.

```
- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section{

    UIView *myView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)];
    UIImageView *myimgvw = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 50)];
    [myimgvw setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"logo.png"]];
    [myView addSubview:myimgvw];

    return myView; 
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer.When I add this,the header image overlays the first row of uitableview.How could I overcome that?

Comment: Goto to xib file->Select that table->Check table view size->Put the value in Header Field "50",or whatever you want.

Answer (score 1):

You haven't shown your code that displays the array content, but I guess you are using something like

```
[dataArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
```

But because you are showing the image at row 0, you need to offset this by -1. In other words, the second row in your table will have indexPath.row = 1, but you need that to be objectAtIndex:0.

Comment: When following your idea, you'll not have the last element of the array.

Comment: @androniennn I don't see why that would be the case. As long as you return the array size + 1 for the number of cells then there's no problem.

Comment: Yep, exactly, in the `numberofrows` delegate we return the arraysize+1 and then we'll always have the last element. That was my fault. I was checking `if(indexPath.row==0)` then return customCell1 else return `indexPath.row-1` customCell2, that way I'll never have the last element.

Answer (score 0):

Then you need to put use indexPath-1 to show text instead of indexPath in else part of above code snippet.